# Event Capturing, Event Bubbling and jQuery.on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling, event-capturing

I have an interesting question about event **capturing**, **bubbling** and `jQuery.on()`.

I have recently learned more about the difference between event capturing and event bubbling and how the two flow differently in and out of the child-parent elements within the DOM.

So to add an event listener with **"event capture direction"** i would use:

`element.addEventListener("click", myFunction, true);`

and to add an event listener with **"event bubble direction"** i would use:

`element.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);`

This is all good and well, but what I want to know is when using `jquery.on()` to add event listeners, how does one specifiy the event direction in terms of **capturing and bubbling**?

currently I am using something like:

`$('parent selector').on('click', 'child selector', function(){alert('just alert something already...');});`

How do I tell jQuery that it needs to add these event listeners in the **"event capture direction"** or the **"event bubble direction"**?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't. jQuery events works with event bubbling it doesn't support capturing.

Also see

- [Why does jQuery event model does not support event Capture and just supports event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163616/why-does-jquery-event-model-does-not-support-event-capture-and-just-supports-eve)

Comment: Hi Arun. I wanted to nominate you for community moderator but you are missing `convention` badge. Are you close to achieving it? (10 posts with score >2 on meta).

Comment: @ArunPJohny I get it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.target to get the exact element that was clicked

```
  $('.parent').on('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('child'))
      // do something
    }
  })
```