# Event Capturing in Jquery

Tags: jquery

How do we do **event capturing** in Jquery. I know all about *event bubbling* and *event capturing* in JavaScript but interested to know if Jquery has something similar for event capturing. ***If not, then how can I extend Jquery code for this additional functionality***. Please guide. Thanks in adv.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop event capturing"? Unregister all capturing event handlers? Convert them to bubbling ones? Or do you mean how to actually **do** capturing event handlers?

Comment: For your reference, I've created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishoreworks/ptv4ajp8/) . This is a simple demonstration of event capturing done via JS. I simply wanted to do this by Jquery. I wanted to know jsfiddle code line `divs[i].addEventListener("click", highlightThis, true)` alternative in jquery

Comment: Yes, I know what capturing is. But how did the word "stop" find its way into your question? Because how can you stop something that isn't even there?

Comment: @Siguza Thanks for correcting me on my query. See! I updated my Question. Now can you please suggest something on regrading my previous comment and updated Question.

Comment: Before you go off extending jQuery, you might wanna have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7163616/2302862). There's a reason jQuery doesn't support capturing.

Comment: @Siguza Can you please give me some hints that if they implement event capturing phase in jquery then what kind of issues may  arise.

Comment: Some browsers simply don't support it, namely IE < 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found the comment
>   [Event Capturing in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091918/event-capturing-in-jquery#comment-50201238)
>   upto my satisfaction. Hence closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery events works with event bubbling and it doesn't support capturing. So, there's no sense to stop event capturing.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680825/event-capturing-event-bubbling-and-jquery-on) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163616/why-does-jquery-event-model-does-not-support-event-capture-and-just-supports-eve) for more information.

Comment: I had guessed it already. Thats why i highlighted the line in my query **If not, then how can I extend Jquery code for this additional functionality** . My area of interest is to know how would i add event capturing phase in jquery if it doesn't have. Hope there must be a way.

Comment: Then you need to write your own library to extend the ability for capturing events.